# Ternary Operator not giving expected result

Tags: c#

I am trying to run the below statement.

```
value = device.WeightLB == null ? string.Empty :
        ((GlobalVariables.MeasurementId == 1) ? 
        (FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightKG) + Constants.KgUnit) : 
        (FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightLB) + Constants.LbUnit));
```

**Expected:**

If `MeasurementId` is `1` then I should get the result in KG.

**Problem:**

If `MeasurementId` is `1` then I am getting the result in Lb.

Am i missing the sequence in which the query should be written (braces sequence) or something else is wrong?

`Constants.KgUnit` will return string kg and 
`Constants.LbUnit` will return string lb

During debugging the values are:

```
GlobalVariables.Measurementid == 1  
device.WeightKG  == 10 
Constants.KgUnit == "kg"
device.WeightLB  == 22.04  
Constants.LbUnit == "lb"
```

Need Help.
The above values is what i am getting.

Comment: Why don't you use `if..else` instead, do you find this more readable?

Comment: Can you check your constants definition? Might be, that you just have switched the definitions and KgUnit is returning lb and vice versa

Comment: `MeasurementId` is definitely not 1.

Comment: What is the data type of `MeasurementId` property

Comment: Your ternary is correctly laid out. Have you stepped through and made sure that the `MeasurementId` *really* is 1, and that `Constants.LbUnit` definitely contains what you want it to?

Comment: If your pound variable is null then the kilogram calculation will not be reached (either).

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line, hover `MeasurementID`, `WeightKG`, `WeightLB`, `KgUnit` and `LbUnit` and tell the values

Comment: is ` device.WeightLB` nullable type variable?

Comment: @PranayRana it won't change anything, will it? I mean if it's not nullable, then `string.Empty` is unreachable, but that's all

Comment: After debugging the values are as below: 
MeasurementId = 1
WeightKG = 10
WeightLB = 22.04
KgUnit = "kg"
LbUnit = "lb"

Comment: what is the type of MeasurementId ?

Comment: and with those values, what is the value of `value` on next line?

Comment: @Antariksh - based on you code you will not receive both  WeightKG = 10 WeightLB = 22.04  because you wrote condtion based on that one of them get exeuctue , right ?

Comment: @Antariksh - my point is if you have MeasurementId = 1 then you should get WeightKG = 10 out of your condition

Comment: @PranayRana `WeightKG`'s value does not depend on the condition. What depends is the value of `value` *after* that line

Comment: @Rafalon - this is code `(GlobalVariables.MeasurementId == 1) ? 
        (FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightKG) + Constants.KgUnit) : 
        (FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightLB) + Constants.LbUnit)` and as per this you will get one outcome only, right ?

Comment: @PranayRana yes, the outcome is `value`

Comment: @Rafalon - so it will return you one value either in KG or LB not both as given in question

Comment: @PranayRana come on, you have 127k rep, don't you know the principle of breakpoint? He's not saying he gets both values, he's saying **`device.WeightKG == 10`** and **`device.WeightLB == 22.04`**

Comment: @Rafalon - this what written `After Debugging the values are:` not written anything about breakpoint

Comment: We need @Antariksh to answer the question that was asked half an hour ago: what is the value of `value` straight after that statement was executed?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://tpcg.io/JMIZfD) using an exact copy/paste of the question code

Answer (score 1):

Try using following code instead:

```
if(device.WeightLB == null)
{
    value = string.Empty;
}
else if(GlobalVariables.MeasurementId == 1)
{
    value = FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightKG) + Constants.KgUnit;
}
else
{
    value = FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightLB) + Constants.LbUnit;
}
```

Comment: While technically correct, and more readable, it is still supposed to do the same as OP's code and doesn't explain why he gets wrong output.

Comment: Yeah, it's much more readable and easier to support. The ternary operator should be used to simplify the code, but not to make it complex.

Comment: @Rafalon maybe this code can help OP debug more effectively?

Comment: it might be interger value `device.WeightLB`, and you code will fail

Comment: @PranayRana Yes, you are right. Updating my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of weird things in this code, as it is very complex the way it is written, always write code which is simple to understand *i.e.* read to third person who is going to maintain you code.

```
value = device.WeightLB == null ? string.Empty :
        ((GlobalVariables.MeasurementId == 1) ? 
        (FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightKG) + Constants.KgUnit) : 
        (FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightLB) + Constants.LbUnit));
```

1. first line is `device.WeightLB == null` then returns empty string. But what if you have value in `device.WeightKG`
2. if not null then it goes in your second ternary condition
3. in your ternary condition `(FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightKG) + Constants.KgUnit))` is not going to execute till you have value for  `device.WeightKG`

//this took 15 min to understand what you written , and hope you got my point.

Why dont you do this in simple manner, and by doing that you will get your answer why you are not getting value

```
if (device.WeightLB == null ) 
   return string.Empty;

//this will not get execute when  device.WeightLB == null 
if( GlobalVariables.MeasurementId == 1) 
       return (FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightKG) + Constants.KgUnit);
else 
       return (FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightLB) + Constants.LbUnit);
```

Comment: Well if you reach point 3, it means `device.WeightLB` is not `null` so it will execute...

Comment: @Rafalon - yes but it till me 15 min to understand, my point is write easy readable code so that easy find out bug ...

Comment: come on, a double ternary is not rocket science, is it ?

Comment: @Boo - its not rocket science but they its written its very difficult to understand it ..

Answer (score 0):

I find it strange that you check WeightLB even if `MeasurementId = 1`. Maybe this is the problem?

What the code does is explained already, what I'm writing here is just a suggestion how to write it in the more readable way:

Extract a method what does only conversion of weight into a string with unit (if possible)

```
private string Calculate(Device device)
{
    if (device.WeightLB == null)
        return string.Empty;

    return GlobalVariables.MeasurementId == 1 ? 
            (FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightKG) + Constants.KgUnit : 
            (FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(device.WeightLB) + Constants.LbUnit));
}
```

What else can be done is to create extensions to write in the fluent style

```
private string Calculate(Device device)
{
    if (device.WeightLB == null)
        return string.Empty;        

    return GlobalVariables.MeasurementId == 1 ? 
            device.WeightKG.BuildDecimal().ToKgUnit(): 
            device.WeightLb.BuildDecimal().ToLbUnit();
}

//Extension implementation
public static class  MyExtensions
{
    public static decimal BuildDecimal(this string value)
    {
        return FormatHelper.BuildDecimal(value);
    }

    public static string ToKgUnit(this decimal value)
    {
        return value+Constants.KgUnit;
    }

    public static string ToLbUnit(this decimal value)
    {
        return value+Constants.LbUnit;
    }
}
```